# How to load translation from same file for both en and en-US language using i18next

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

We are using [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) and maintaining translations only for language 'en' and 'fr'. Which is creating an issue for us, when the browser preferred language is 'en-US' the translations are not getting loaded, since there is no separate file maintained for en-US

Can someone suggest the possibility to use the same file for similar languages like 'en', 'en-US' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a custom implementation for I18n.

```js
<IntlProvider
  defaultLocale="en"
  locale={locale}
  messages={messages[language]}
>
```

Then export all translation as:

```js
export const messages = {
  en: EnTranslation,
  fr: FrTranslation
}
```

and based on users' locale, you can set `language` in your store. Since you are in command, you can do something like this:

```js
const locales = {
  en: 'en',
  'en-US': 'en',
  'en-UK': 'en',
  fr: 'fr'
}

const setLanguage = (action) => {
  const locale = locales[action.payload]
  return {...state, locale }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rajesh. I able to resolve the issue based on your suggestion